# Как в стиле задать всех кнопок которые находятся в StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-стили

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. У меня есть в StackPanel вложенный Button, хочу чтобы стили применялись для всех этих Button-ов. Аналогом в css является .SomeClass > Button

Comment: Положите стиль для кнопок в ресурсы `StackPanel`.

Comment: StackPanel.Resources->Style для Button без указания ключа